# Typeahead/Search/Suggestions logic in React if data is coming from array of objects rather than normal string array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Created a Typeahead/Search/Suggestion component which is working fine as attached where data is coming from normal array of string.

> Now My data is array of objects , Like this :

```
const carBrands = [
  {
    label: "Alice Bowen",
    text: "name@email.com"
  },
  {
    label: "John smith",
    text: "name@email.com"
  },
  {
    label: "Jenny fey",
    text: "name@email.com"
  },
  {
    label: "Peter parker",
    text: "name@email.com"
  }
];
```

> And expected Output is like :

```
name@email.com
Alice Bowen
-------------------
name@email.com
Alice Bowen
-------------------
name@email.com
Alice Bowen
-------------------
```

Please find the working code below :
https://codesandbox.io/s/n7vn6n42xj

I am confused in the filter logic as I need to filter the list on the basis of emailaddresses.

Your valuable help is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you send the list as a list of strings so

```
<Typeahead list={carBrands} />
```

becomes

```
<Typeahead list={carBrands.map(t => t.text)} />
```

Or you make the typehead component a bit more generic by passing a lookupKey

```
<Typeahead list={carBrands} lookupKey="text" />
```

And you change the onChange method as follows

```
onChange = value => {
let {list, lookupKey} = this.props;
if (lookupKey){
  list = list.map(t => t[lookupKey]);
}
this.setState({
  value,
  showSuggestions: true,
  selectedIndex: null,
  suggestions: list.filter(
    item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0
  ),
});
};
```

Comment: What to do if I need to show the corresponding name just below the email address ? but filtering should be done on basis of email id's only.
Please check my expected output !!

Comment: Where do you want this output exactly? on the link you sent i only see a search box

Comment: When we type something in searchbox ..we filter by emails right ! So , In  the suggestions when it get opened, I would like to have the name just below all the corresponding email ids..

Comment: Please check this [codepin](https://codesandbox.io/s/yq4yljn7p9), its the same idea but we add the texts below

Comment: @Swordys he wants it to show both (label & text) at the same time

Comment: @MoaeadYahya Yes, he needs to pass additional prop so function knows what type of data is being filtered. This was just object filtering example.

Comment: @Swordys got yeah, yeah with the last link i sent it should do the same thing

Comment: I think you have attached my link only !! Suggestion list should contain email address and just below that name of the person...

Comment: Please refresh, here's the link again https://codesandbox.io/s/yq4yljn7p9

Comment: @Swordys : yes..but what if I want label too just below email id in suggestions list ?

Comment: Refresh again please

Comment: @MoaeadYahya : yes ..Cool..thats perfect !!

Comment: @pourushsinghgaur glad it worked as you wanted, please set as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @MoaeadYahya Thankyou !!

Comment: @MoaeadYahya  : I have one more requirement. I need to make it controlled component in react.I am calling from parent with passing value,onChange,carBrands as properties.In child,I am calling another function on its onChange and trying to capture the value with event and setting up the state.

Comment: @MoaeadYahya:But in this,suggestion are not getting open.Request you to please guide.
Thanks